# Ignore git submodule without read permission

Tags: git, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

**The situation:**

I have a repository that has a submodule.

Normal people (like me) don't have read permissions for this submodule which isn't really a problem as it isn't required to run the project.

My problem is that every time I check something out I get errors telling me that the submodule update failed because the submodule remote couldn't be read:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current revision in submodule path
```

no surprise ...

I tried to remove it manually from .gitmodules and then use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged .gitmodules
```

but this only works until the next checkout as submodules seem to get special treatment.

I tried putting .gitmodules into .gitignore or .git/info/exclude but git ignored that, reported .gitmodules as changed and gave me the original one again at checkout.

**My question:**

How do I suppress these errors and completely ignore the existence of this submodule locally... including all further remote changes that try to reintroduce it?

---

**Note:** Please assume that the solution has to stay on my end and requires no changes on the remote side... as they will not happen (already tried talking to the repo admin)

Comment: What do you mean by no read permission for submodule? You have cloned project with git submodule & update & init? What happens if you do `git submodule deinit -f .`, and pull afterwards? Are you able to replicate this on local machine (changing owner and removing rights to access to submodule repo)?

Comment: I mean that I can't access the remote part of the submodule as I only get permission denied as the response. And no, I never was able to do a submodule update & init in this project because remote couldn't be read. Executing `git submodule deinit -f .` successfully removed it from the config and using assume unchanged on the now missing submodule path seems to work (also added the submodule path and .gitmodules to .git/info/exclude) ...This seems to work (at least on linux) I can test if it solves the problem on windows too in some hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to replicate this situation, but as per discussion in comments

```
git submodule deinit -f .
```

helped. If someone stumbles here, from [docume](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)[ntation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) one might find out that during init, actual `git pull` is done on submodule. So If You had no permissions to access remote submodule repository, locally git had no master branch, no commits to checkout, and that was the meaning behind error message.

---

**Update:** if you are using a gui like SourceTree or SmartGit, check the repository settings and disable the auto-update of submodules.
Depending on your setup only disabling "Initialize new submodules" may already fix the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use

`git config --global submodule.<module>.update none`

Where  is the name of the submodule you want to update.

Setting the value to none means that the submodule will not be checked out or updated.  Since this is global it will apply across all repos.

[From here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3339?focusedCommentId=1612928&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1612928)